# How to correctly handle exceptions from the service (spring boot rest)

Tags: spring-boot, exception

When building a rest api using spring boot what is the best way to handle exceptions from the service level and **pass** them to the controller, so the client gets a **custom json error message**.

```
{
    "message": "some error"
}
```

**Endpoint from controller**

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody @Valid LoginDto loginDto) {
    return gson.toJson(userService.login(loginDto.getUsername(), loginDto.getPassword()));
}
```

**Service level code**

```
public LoginResponseDto login(String username, String password) {

        try {
            //performs some checks
            ...
            return new LoginResponseDto(token.get());
        } catch (AuthenticationException e){
            LOGGER.info("Log in failed for user {}", username);
        }
    return new LoginResponseDto("login failed");
}
```

**LoginResponseDto class**

```
String token;
String message;

public LoginResponseDto(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

Currently it is obviously returning the correctly message but not the correct status code, it will show status 200 with the error message in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options:

1) Returning a message:

If you want to return a message something like this,

```
{
    "message": "some error"
}
```

What you can do is:

Option 1: Create a custom POJO class for error message and return the reference to the object of that POJO class.

Something like this:

**ErrorMessage.java**

```
package org.example;

public class ErrorMessage {
    private String message;

    public ErrorMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**Request Handler Method in Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/login{?username, password}")
public ErrorMessage isUserAuthenticated(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) { 

    if (username.toLowerCase().contentEquals("root") && password.contentEquals("system")) {
        return new ErrorMessage("authenticated");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Option 2: Create a Map and insert key-value pairs that you want to have in the message.

Like this:

```
@GetMapping("/login{?username, password}")
public Map<String, String> isUserAuthenticated(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) { 
    Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();

    if (username.toLowerCase().contentEquals("root") && password.contentEquals("system")) {
        message.put("message", "authenticated");
    }

    return message;
}
```

2) Returning an error status code (highly recommended by me):

You may use ResponseEntity for this purpose.

```
@GetMapping("/login{?username, password}")
public ResponseEntity<?> isUserAuthenticated(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) { 
    if (username.toLowerCase().contentEquals("root") && password.contentEquals("system")) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```